# Linking to a library in Xcode - Static or dynamic

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a C++ project and I am linking to an external library (using all of its headers and source files). I did this by going into the project configuration and adding the `source.a` library that i wanted to link to. Now my question is how do I know if my library is linked to my program statically or dynamically. I have read numerous thread about the types of linking however i am still not sure about the type of linking I have. Any suggestions on this regard would be helpful

Comment: I am not asking for the difference. I have inherited a project in XCODE and want to know how I can find out if its being statically linked or dynamically linked

Comment: It's static. If it were dynamic you would have added a .dylib file instead (which apparently you don't have one of).

Comment: Thansk for clearing that up. Can you add that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did this by going into the project configuration and adding the `source.a` library...

It's static. If it were dynamic you would have added a .dylib file instead (which apparently you don't have one of).